# return the largest node from a node neighborhood

Tags: python, networkx

I was hoping to go through graph G composed of n nodes. And for each nth node open the dict of its neighbors. Find out which neighbor has the largest numeric attribute.  There can be at least 100 neighbors. and return a list of each node and its largest neighbor i.e.

```
[node,biggestneighbor]
[node,biggestneighbor]
[node,biggestneighbor]
```

The attributes data for a node look like this:

```
G.node[0]

{'type': 'a', 'pos': [0.76, 0.11]}
```

and the attribute I am interested in is

```
G.node[0]['pos'][0]

0.76
```

Does anyone know if this exists? Or if not does the starting logic look like a good starting point? or does a smarter person have a much better idea?

```
def thebiggestneighbor(G,attribute,nodes=None):

    if nodes is None:
        node_set = G
    else:
        node_set = G.subgraph(nodes)
    node=G.node
    for u,nbrsdict in G.adjacency_iter():
        if u not in node_set:
            continue
            for v,eattr in nbrsdict.items():
                vattr=node[v].get(attribute,None)
          #  then something like this but for many nodes. probably better subtraction 
          #  of all nodes from each other and which one yeilds the biggest numner
          #  
          #  if x.[vattra] > x.[vattrb]  then
          #      a
          #  elif x.[vattra] < x.[vattrb] then
          #      b 

            yield (u,b)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like solving problems like this with the right datastructure:

```
#nodes = [ (att_n, [(att_n, n_idx).. ] ), ... ]  where each node is known by its index
#in the outer list. Each node is represented with a tuple: att_n the numeric attribute, 
#and a list of neighbors. Neighbors have their numeric attribute repeated
#eg. node 1 has neighbors 2, and 3. node 2 has neighbor 1 and 4, etc..: 
nodes = [ (192, [ (102, 2), (555, 3)] ), 
          (102, [ (192, 1), (333, 4) ] ), 
          (555, [ (192, 1),] ), ... 
    ]  
#then to augment nodes so the big neighbor is visible:
nodesandbigneighbor=[ (att_n, neighbors, max(neighbors)) for att_n, neighbors in nodes]
```

Also if you maintain the sort order of the neighbor lists from low numeric attribute to high, then then you can do:

```
nodesandbigneighbor=[ (att_n, neighbors, neighbors[-1]) for att_n, neighbors in nodes]
```

which will be faster (at the expense of node insert time), but then you are effectively solving the problem at insert time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the problem, you would do a O(n*m) [n=nodes, m=avg(neighbors)] operation by iterating over all the nodes and foreach node iterating over its neighbors. Worst case it's a O(n^2). Also you have an indentation problem as most of your code is after a "continue" statement, so it wont be executed.

Code example

```
node=G.node
output=[]
for u,nbrsdict in G.adjacency_iter():
    if u not in node_set:
        continue
    max={'value':0,'node':None}
    for v,eattr in nbrsdict.items():
        vattr=node[v].get(attribute,None)
        if vattr>max['value']:
            max={'value':vattr,'node':node}
    output.append((node,max['node']))
return output
```

Comment: if you maintain the neighbors in lists sorted by numeric attribute, the problem becomes O(n). Though the time to add a node would be O(nlogn).

Comment: thank you luke, im new to python so im trying out ypur code.  for now its giving me an output not as i expected, i.e. for 20 nodes in G its giving me much more than a list 20 elemnts long.I will need to work on this...